# Relationship between Collaboration Group and Feed Item (of type QuestionPost)

Tags: community, chatter, chatter-groups, collaborationgroup

I am researching into migration of chatter data between two instances of Salesforce. Specifically I need to migrate chatter data within Collaboration Groups in a Community. I found all the posts from within the groups within the FeedItem table, including the related "answers", which really are just records in FeedComment table. What I cannot find is the relationship which makes the FeedItem records appear under a specific CollaborationGroup.

I looked through every relationship on FeedItem, and cannot find how it is linked to specific CollaborationGroup. I took one FeedItem as an example, it appears under one of the CollaborationGroup records, but its ParentId refers to a User record, RelatedRecordId refers to a ContentDocument record, InsertedById refers to user record, CreatedById refers to User record. I don't see any junction objects either, which link that post (FeedItem) to the CollaborationGroup record.

Does anyone know how to identify the child FeedItem records of type QuestionPost in a given CollaborationGroup record?

Comment: The relationship would be `ParentId`. Did they get brought into the group via `@mention`?

Comment: As I mentioned in my post, the FeedItem's ParentId field contains reference to the User record, not the CollaborationGroup record. I don't see a direct reference of the FeedItem record to CollaborationGroup record, yet the FeedItem appears under that specific group. The FeedItem record was created by posting a question into the CollaborationGroup, e.g. not via @mention.

Comment: Actually, I read more about mention, and it seems like this may be exactly what is happening here, the post was created by a given user directly and then the group was simply mentioned. So, while the post is directly related to the creating user (ParentId contains user ID), the mention puts the post in the group's feed. I will need to verify this by extracting the mentions somehow. Thanks @AdrianLarson

Answer (score 0):

There is an object called `CollaborationGroupFeed` which has a field called `parentId`. `ParentId` field belongs to the collaborationGroup and id of collaborationGroupFeed belongs to the feed id. You also have a field called `type` which gives us whether it is `QuestionPost` or `AdvancedTextPost` or any other type.

so your query would be something like

```
select id, type, parentId from CollaborationGroupFeed where type='QuestionPost'
```

will give you feeds of `questionpost`

For more details please go through **usage** part of this link --https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_collaborationgroup.htm